# Legend of fieldset is align in the center by default

Tags: java, web, primefaces

I'm working on a project with PrimeFaces 3.2.2 and I want to use a `p:fieldset` in a form. I saw in the documentation that the legend is aligned to the left by default, the problem I have is that the legend is aligned to the center, I tried using the style attribute, and I looked for solutions but I did not find any helpful.

The fieldset is inside a `p:dialog`, I thought it was the problem but no.

This is the definition of the fieldset:

```
<p:fieldset legend="Simple Fieldset">
  <h:panelGrid >
    <h:outputText value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone ..." />
   </h:panelGrid>
</p:fieldset>
```

But always the legend is shown like this:

[image]

and for better UI visibility I want the legend like this:

[image]

I tried searching for attributes in the `style` tag but I have no success. I want to know if I have a problem with the order of tags, or maybe is the version I'm using. Thanks in advance.